# Cambiar color de pestaña seleccionada en ttk.Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy creando una aplicación en Python 3.6 que tiene varias pestañas y estoy utilizando el widget `Notebook` de Tkinter. Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar una de las pestañas se aprecie claramente cual es la que esta seleccionada cambiando el color de la pestaña.

Por defecto se ve de un tono mas blanco pero no es suficiente, dejo un ejemplo de lo que intento decir:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()

nb = ttk.Notebook(width=200, height=200)
nb.pressed_index = None
f1 = tkinter.Frame(nb, background="red")
f2 = tkinter.Frame(nb, background="green")
f3 = tkinter.Frame(nb, background="blue")
nb.add(f1, text='Red', padding=3)
nb.add(f2, text='Green', padding=3)
nb.add(f3, text='Blue', padding=3)
nb.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT**

Perdona FJSevilla, como podría integrar lo que me has dado con este ejemplo que tengo en mi aplicacion?? Este estilo lo que hace es poner un icono para cerrar las pestañas.

```
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure('.',background=self.bg_2)
    style.element_create("close", "image", "img_close",
        ("active", "pressed", "!disabled", "img_closepressed"),
        ("active", "!disabled", "img_closeactive"), border=10, sticky='n')

    style.layout("ButtonNotebook", [("ButtonNotebook.client", {"sticky": ""})])
    style.layout("ButtonNotebook.Tab", [
        ("ButtonNotebook.tab", {"sticky": "", "children":
            [("ButtonNotebook.padding", {"side": "top", "sticky": "",
                                         "children":
                [("ButtonNotebook.focus", {"side": "top", "sticky": "",
                                           "children":
                    [("ButtonNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                     ("ButtonNotebook.close", {"side": "right", "sticky": 'n'})]
                })]
            })]
        })]
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes definir tu propio estilo y especificar el color que debe tener la pestaña seleccionada. Un ejemplo.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk


root = tkinter.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
settings = {"TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [5, 1],
                                            "background": "#fdd57e"
                                           },
                              "map": {"background": [("selected", "#C70039"), 
                                                     ("active", "#fc9292")],
                                      "foreground": [("selected", "#ffffff"),
                                                     ("active", "#000000")]

                                     }
                              }
           }  


style.theme_create("mi_estilo", parent="alt", settings=settings)
style.theme_use("mi_estilo")


nb = ttk.Notebook(width=200, height=200)
nb.pressed_index = None
f1 = tkinter.Frame(nb)
f2 = tkinter.Frame(nb)
f3 = tkinter.Frame(nb)
nb.add(f1, text='Pestaña 1')
nb.add(f2, text='Pestaña 2')
nb.add(f3, text='Pestaña 3')
nb.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No obstante, no es posible definir estas propiedades para una pestaña individualmente, al menos yo no conozco ninguna forma de hacerlo. Si quieres que cada pestaña tenga un color distinto al ser seleccionada, lo que se puede hacer es usar el evento `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` y modificar el estilo de forma dinámica cada vez que se seleccione una nueva pestaña. Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, por ejemplo:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk


root = tkinter.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()    
settings = {"TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [5, 1],
                                            "background": "#fdd57e"
                                            }}}  
style.theme_create("mi_estilo", parent="alt", settings=settings)
style.theme_use("mi_estilo")


def on_tab(event):
    global tab_styles
    global style
    nb = event.widget
    tab = nb.tab(nb.select(), "text")
    st = tab_styles[tab]
    style.map('TNotebook.Tab', **st)

tab_styles = {}
nb = ttk.Notebook(width=200, height=200)
nb.pressed_index = None

f1 = tkinter.Frame(nb, background="red")
f2 = tkinter.Frame(nb, background="green")
f3 = tkinter.Frame(nb, background="blue")

nb.add(f1, text="Rojo")
tab_styles["Rojo"] = {"background": [("selected", "red")],
                      "foreground": [("selected", "#ffffff")]
                     }
nb.add(f2, text="Verde")
tab_styles["Verde"] = {"background": [("selected", "green")],
                      "foreground": [("selected", "#ffffff")]
                     }

nb.add(f3, text="Azul")
tab_styles["Azul"] = {"background": [("selected", "blue")],
                      "foreground": [("selected", "#ffffff")]
                     }

nb.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
nb.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", on_tab)


root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Edición

Si creas tu propio widget derivando de ttk.Notebook, el estilo de las pestañas se aplica igual, solo que usar el nombre correcto de nuestro widgets:

```
 style.map('ButtonNotebook.Tab', background = [("selected", "#C70039"),
                                               ("active", "#fc9292")],
                                 foreground = [("selected", "#ffffff"),
                                               ("active", "#000000")]
                 )
```

Un ejemplo completo con un botón de cierre en las pestañas, usando una imágen, y aplicando el estilo personalizado para el fondo de las mismas usado anteriormente:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



class ButtonNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    _initialized = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._initialized:
            self._initialize()
            self._inititialized = True

        kwargs["style"] = "ButtonNotebook"
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._active = None

        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_tab_close_press, True)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_tab_close_release)

    def on_tab_close_press(self, event):
        name = self.identify(event.x, event.y)
        if name == "tab_btn_close":
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            self.state(['pressed'])
            self._active = index

    def on_tab_close_release(self, event):
        if not self.instate(['pressed']):
            return None

        name =  self.identify(event.x, event.y)

        if name == "tab_btn_close":
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            if self._active == index:
                self.forget(index)
                self.event_generate("<<NotebookTabClosed>>")

        self.state(["!pressed"])
        self._active = None

    def _initialize(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            style.theme_use('winnative')

        self.images = (
            tk.PhotoImage("img_close", data='''
                          R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2f///////////////yH5
                          BAEKAAIALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMUCCAsCmO5OBVl8OKhoV3e9jQOkAAAOw==
                           '''),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closeactive", data='''
                          R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2f///////////////yH5
                          BAEKAAMALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMPCDA8+gw+GGlVbWKqmwMJADs=
                          ''' ),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closepressed", data='''
                          R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2f///////////////yH5B
                          AEKAAMALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMPGDE8+gw+GGlVbWKqmwsJADs=
                          ''')
        )

        style.element_create("tab_btn_close", "image", "img_close",
                            ("active", "pressed", "!disabled", "img_closepressed"),
                            ("active", "!disabled", "img_closeactive"), border=8, sticky='')

        style.layout("ButtonNotebook", [("ButtonNotebook.client", {"sticky": "nswe"})])
        style.layout("ButtonNotebook.Tab", [
            ("ButtonNotebook.tab", {
                "sticky": "nswe", 
                "children": [
                    ("ButtonNotebook.padding", {
                        "side": "top", 
                        "sticky": "nswe",
                        "children": [
                            ("ButtonNotebook.focus", {
                                "side": "top", 
                                "sticky": "nswe",
                                "children": [
                                    ("ButtonNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                    ("ButtonNotebook.tab_btn_close", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                ]
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ])

        style.configure("ButtonNotebook.Tab", background="#fdd57e")         
        style.map('ButtonNotebook.Tab', background = [("selected", "#C70039"),
                                                      ("active", "#fc9292")],
                                        foreground = [("selected", "#ffffff"),
                                                      ("active", "#000000")]
                 ) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    nb = ButtonNotebook(width=200, height=200)
    nb.pressed_index = None
    f1 = tk.Frame(nb)
    f2 = tk.Frame(nb)
    f3 = tk.Frame(nb)
    nb.add(f1, text='Pestaña 1')
    nb.add(f2, text='Pestaña 2')
    nb.add(f3, text='Pestaña 3')
    nb.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este ejemplo está inspirado en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459376/7131499) de Bryan Oakley en el sitio en inglés.

> **Nota:** las imágenes son .gif de 8 bits con un tamaño de 8 x 8 pixeles codificados en Base64. Se pueden cargar desde otra fuente, como un archivo, igual que hariamos con una imágen cualquiera.

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla, es justo lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: He editado la pregunta FJSevilla, porque no consigo integrar tu código con el estilo que ya tenía.

Comment: Alguna idea? Porfavor??

Comment: @AlfredoLopezRodes perdona, he estado un poco liado y se me había pasado tu comentario anterior. He editado la respuesta, mira al final a ver si esto te aclara el problema. Un saludo.

Comment: gracias por volver a contestar, me pasa algo muy raro, he copiado y pegado tal cual tu código en un archivo de ejemplo, y funciona todo bien menos el fondo de la pestaña que no cambia de color, sin embargo el color de la fuente si que cambia. En mi caso es un gran problema ya que no utilizo texto para las pestañas si no iconos. Entonces necesito que cambie el fondo y no lo hace. Por otra parte al hacer clic sobre el icono de cerrar, mantenerlo y apartar el cursor me devuelve este error y tampoco se porque:

_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got ""

Comment: Recalcar que estoy trabajando con Python 3.6 y en Windows 10, no se si tendrá algo que ver... Pero es muy raro.

Comment: El error  se debe a que el evento "release" tiene lugar fuera de la región de pestañas, no tiene realmente importancia pero es trivial evitarlo, lo he corregido. En cuanto al fondo, ¿mi código tal cual sin modificar nada ya presenta el problema? ¿Fallan todos los fondos o solo el fondo por defecto (el amarillo)?¿O el de activo (rojizo claro)?¿O el de selección (rojizo oscuro)? La versión de Python no es un problema, lo de Windows si puede ser importante , por desgracia ahora mismo no puedo probar el código en este sistema...

Comment: Vale lo del error no me importa, fallan todos los fondos y me da que va a ser al ejecutarlo en Windows :(

Comment: Buenos días FJSevilla, acabo de probar el nuevo código y me lanza el siguiente error:


  File "C:/Users/Alfredo/Desktop/Sin título 0.py", line 47, in _initialize
    self.style.theme_use('winnative')

AttributeError: 'ButtonNotebook' object has no attribute 'style'

Comment: He quitado el "self." delante de style dentro de la función initialice() y ya funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ha ayudado un montón. Quería comentarte otra duda, yo antes tenia unas funciones para cerrar las pestañas en las que controlaba una serie de variables para saber si debo cerrar esa pestaña en funcion de la variable y el indice. El tema es que accedia a esas variables como "self.variable", pero ahora en esta clase SELF hace referencia a la propia clase, y no se como adaptarlo.

Comment: Ups! si era un error tipográfico, corregido, gracias por el aviso. En cuanto a lo otro. `self` hace referencia a  la propia instancia de la clase como siempre, la instancia `ButtonNotebook` en este caso, la cual hereda de `ttk.Notbook` todos sus métodos y atributos. Yo no implementaría lógica alguna en ella, deberías poder usarla exactamente igual que antes, como si fuera un `ttk.Notebook`, con solo substituir la antigua instancia de tu widget `ttk.Notebook` por una instancia de`ButtonNotebook`.

Comment: Sin conocer la estructura de tu anterior código no es posible dar una respuesta concreta me temo, si no das con la tecla puedes crear una nueva pregunta agregando el código mínimo reproducible que consideres oportuno. Un saludo.

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, he sacado las funciones para 'cerrar pestañas' fuera de la clase y funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Perdona FJSevilla, me queda una duda, esto funciona perfectamente pero tengo un "problema". Me cambia el estilo de toda la aplicación, los controles de lista desplegables Combobox y un widget Treeview que tengo para mostrar una tabla cambian de apariencia. Y una progressbar que tengo también. Esto se puede cambiar?