# Como establecer color al widget de notebook en python

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen dia amigos

Sigo aprendiendo mas de python y mientras mas aprendo mas dudas me salen XD, estoy intentando establecerle el color a mis pestañas pero no puedo, tengo 2 pestañas "alumnos" y "profesores" y dentro de la pestaña estan los nombres de cada uno, pude colocar el color gris en un frame pero alrededor aparece de color blanco :S estuve buscando en la documentacion de Tkinter en notebook y no esta la propiedad background ni bg como puedo cambiar el color? dejo mi codigo y la imagen para que se observe el problema mas graficamente

```
  class Product:

      def __init__(self, window):

         #Ventana

         self.wind = window
         self.wind.title('Escuela Secundaria tecnica # 91')
         self.wind.configure(background = 'gray')

         #Pestañas
         self._tab_control = ttk.Notebook(self.wind)
         self.tab1 = tkinter.Frame(self._tab_control, bg = 'gray')
         self._tab_control.add(self.tab1, text='Alumnos')
         lbl1 = Label(self.tab1, text= 'Jorge Alberto Rodriguez Gomez')
         self._tab_control.grid(row= 1, column = 0) 
         lbl1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

         ######Pestaña 2
         self.tab2 = tkinter.Frame(self._tab_control, bg = 'gray')
         self._tab_control.add(self.tab2, text='Profesores')
         lbl2 = Label(self.tab2, text= 'Roberto Macías')
         self._tab_control.grid(row= 1, column = 0) 
         lbl2.grid(column=0, row=0)


   if __name__ == '__main__':
      window = Tk()
      application = Product(window)
      window.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se ve claramente que alrededor de las pestañas esta de color gris pero en las pestañas esta de color blanco, que me hace falta hacer???
Gracias!!!!

Comment: Si lo que quieres es cambiar el color de las propias pestañas, posible relacionada [Cambiar color de pestaña seleccionada en ttk.Notebook](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/198057/15089). ¿O te refieres al fondo del propio notebook?

Comment: Hola Amigo FJSevilla me refiero al fondo propio T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los detalles del aspecto de los componentes `ttk` se cambian mediante estilos (a través de `ttk.Style()` como mostraré luego). Estos estilos se agrupan en "temas".

Los temas disponibles dependen de la plataforma en que ejecutes el programa. Puedes obtener la lista de temas en tu plataforma consultando `ttk.Style().theme_names()`. Encontrarás que en OSX tienes el tema `'aqua'` que imita el aspecto de otras ventanas OSX, mientras que en Windows tienes el tema `'vista'`, con un aspecto más típico de Windows. Estos temas no están disponibles fuera de las correspondientes plataformas.

Por defecto Tk usará un tema adecuado a tu plataforma, de modo que la aplicación tenga un aspecto "nativo" (similar al de otras aplicaciones en tu ordenador). Así en OSX elegirá el tema `'aqua'`, mientras que en Windows usará el tema `'vista'`.

Por eso, tu aplicación se ve diferente según donde la ejecutes. En la captura de pantalla que adjuntas se ve su aspecto en OSX, y así se vería tu misma aplicación (sin cambios) al ser ejecutada en Windows:

[image: Muestra en Windows]

Para cambiar el estilo de los tab, puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente, intentando poner fondo verde y letra más grande (esto debes añadirlo antes de crear `ttk.Notebook()`):

```
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("TNotebook.Tab", background="green", font="helvetica 24")
```

Ahora bien, si ejecutamos el programa vemos que, tanto en Windows como en Mac OSX, ha obedecido el cambio de la fuente, pero no el color de fondo:

[image: En Windows] [image: En OSX]

Y es que ciertos estilos no pueden cambiarse en ciertos temas. En concreto, el color de fondo de un botón (que es como se implementa el tab) no puede cambiarse ni en el tema "aqua" ni en el "vista".

La solución a esto sería usar otro tema de los disponibles, como por ejemplo el tema "classic". Este tema tiene el inconveniente de que ya no parece nativo (ni en Windows ni en OSX), pero la ventaja de que se ve igual en ambos operativos, y que es más configurable. Harías lo siguiente:

```
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.theme_use("classic")
    style.configure("TNotebook.Tab", background="green", font="helvetica 24")
```

Y vemos cómo ahora sí que cambia el fondo del botón, además del tipo de letra, y cómo se ve igual en ambos operativos:

[image: En Windows] [image: En OSX]

Estoy usando deliberadamente unos colores horribles, para que se vea más claramente si estos estilos están siendo aplicados o no.

**Ampliación**

Si quieres cambiar también el color del "tab activo" (por ejemplo rojo) debes usar:

```
    style.map("TNotebook.Tab", background = [("selected", "red")])
```

Como ves la configuración de todo esto es bastante horrible, y tiene poco qué ver con Python. `tkinter` es un *envoltorio* sobre Tcl/Tk, que es la biblioteca que hay por debajo para hacer todo el trabajo, que tiene ya más de 30 años, y a la que debemos esta API tan fea. Es en realidad la documentación de Tcl/Tk la que deberías consultar para estos detalles, y no la de tkinter que no entra tan a fondo en el tema de estilos.

De todas formas, si vas a hacer cosas más complejas y puedes elegir, yo te diría que en lugar de `tkinter` uses otro framework más moderno para GUIs en Python, como [PyQT5](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/) o [wxwidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/)

Comment: Ohhh muchas gracias!!!! entonces ya es cuestion del sistema operativo, tengo una duda mas, entonces si uso ese pequeño programa en windows y le quito el gris oscuro se vera mucho mejor en general toda la ventana???? muchas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: No entiendo bien esta pregunta, pero ¡prueba! Ya sabes que "para gustos se hicieron los colores" :-)

Comment: Jejeje lo siento pero ya corriendo el programa me respondí solito!!!! agradezco mucho tu valiosa respuesta!!!