# ¿Cómo colocar botones de cierre para determinadas pestañas con ttk.Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

**¡Hola comunidad!**

Estoy desarrollando una GUI con `tkinter` donde se implementa el widget `ttk.Notebook`.

Deseo colocar una pestaña de "INICIO", con otros widgets en su interior, entre los que destacan algunos botones que deberán crear pestañas adicionales. Conseguí una solución parcial a esta problemática, ya que pude crear pestañas con un botón de cierre pero, estás se aplican a TODAS las pestañas de la interfaz.

Es decir, la pestaña de "INICIO" no debería poder cerrarse, a diferencia de las pestañas que se crean/crearán de acuerdo a la selección que el usuario deseé ejecutar. Es común que estas pestañas tengan un icono o botón de cierre, pero de forma predeterminada el widget `ttk.Notebook` no lo proporciona. A continuación, se muestra el problema de forma muy general:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ButtonNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    _initialized = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._initialized:
            self._initialize()
            self._inititialized = True

        kwargs["style"] = "ButtonNotebook"
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._active = None

        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_tab_close_press, True)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_tab_close_release)

    def on_tab_close_press(self, event):
        name = self.identify(event.x, event.y)
        if name == "tab_btn_close":
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            self.state(['pressed'])
            self._active = index

    def on_tab_close_release(self, event):
        if not self.instate(['pressed']):
            return None

        name =  self.identify(event.x, event.y)

        if name == "tab_btn_close":
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            if self._active == index:
                self.forget(index)
                self.event_generate("<<NotebookTabClosed>>")

        self.state(["!pressed"])
        self._active = None

    def _initialize(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            style.theme_use('winnative')

        self.images = (
            tk.PhotoImage("img_close", data='''
                          R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2f///////////////yH5
                          BAEKAAIALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMUCCAsCmO5OBVl8OKhoV3e9jQOkAAAOw==
                           '''),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closeactive", data='''
                          R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2f///////////////yH5
                          BAEKAAMALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMPCDA8+gw+GGlVbWKqmwMJADs=
                          ''' ),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closepressed", data='''
                          R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2f///////////////yH5B
                          AEKAAMALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMPGDE8+gw+GGlVbWKqmwsJADs=
                          ''')
        )

        style.element_create("tab_btn_close", "image", "img_close",
                            ("active", "pressed", "!disabled", "img_closepressed"),
                            ("active", "!disabled", "img_closeactive"), border=8, sticky='')

        style.layout("ButtonNotebook", [("ButtonNotebook.client", {"sticky": "nswe"})])
        style.layout("ButtonNotebook.Tab", [
            ("ButtonNotebook.tab", {
                "sticky": "nswe", 
                "children": [
                    ("ButtonNotebook.padding", {
                        "side": "top", 
                        "sticky": "nswe",
                        "children": [
                            ("ButtonNotebook.focus", {
                                "side": "top", 
                                "sticky": "nswe",
                                "children": [
                                    ("ButtonNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                    ("ButtonNotebook.tab_btn_close", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                ]
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ])

        style.configure("ButtonNotebook.Tab", background="#fdd57e")         
        style.map('ButtonNotebook.Tab', background = [("selected", "Blue"),
                                                      ("active", "red")],
                                        foreground = [("selected", "#ffffff"),
                                                      ("active", "#000000")]
                 ) 

class MiApp:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("650x250")                

        self.nb = ButtonNotebook(self.root, width=200, height=200)
        self.nb.pressed_index = None
        self.fm = tk.Frame(self.nb)

        self.nb.add(self.fm, text='INICIO')
        self.nb.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        tk.Label(self.fm, text='Bienvenido a mi programa').grid()
        tk.Button(self.fm, text='SUMAR', command=self.sumar).grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
        tk.Button(self.fm, text='RESTAR', command=self.restar).grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

    def sumar(self):
        fm_sumar = tk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(fm_sumar, text='Pestaña de sumar')
        self.nb.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

    def restar(self):
        fm_restar = tk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(fm_restar, text='Pestaña de restar')
        self.nb.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = MiApp()
    master.mainloop()
```

Debo recalcar que la clase `ButtonNotebook(ttk.Notebook)` proviene de una respuesta a una publicación hecha dentro del foro: [Cambiar color de pestaña seleccionada en ttk.Notebook](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198057/cambiar-color-de-pesta%C3%B1a-seleccionada-en-ttk-notebook)

**¡Gracias por sus comentarios y sugerencias!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se me ocurre una forma de dejar a solo una pestaña sin el botón de cierre, es decir, aplicar un estilo diferente a esa pestaña en concreto.

Lo que no es muy difícil de implementar dado que depende enteramente de Python y no de TCL/TK, es hacer que se ignore el click sobre el botón de cierre para esa pestaña. Obviamente no es lo mismo estéticamente que no poner el botón en esa pestaña, pero el resultado es el mismo, el usuario no podrá cerrarla.

Una opción es sobrescribir el método `add` y añadirle un argumento que nos permita especificar si essa pestaña puede o no ser cerrada. Para la implementación basta con usar un contenedor que liste los indices de las pestañas no cerrables y en el método `on_tab_close_release` ignorar el evento para ellas.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self._initialized:
        self._initialize()
        self._inititialized = True

    kwargs["style"] = "ButtonNotebook"
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self._active = None
    self._non_closable_tabs = set()  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_tab_close_press, True)
    self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_tab_close_release)
```

---

```
def add(self, *args, closable=True, **kwargs):
    super().add(*args, **kwargs)
    if not closable:
        self._non_closable_tabs.add(self.index(self.tabs()[-1]))
```

---

```
def on_tab_close_release(self, event):
    if not self.instate(['pressed']):
        return None

    name =  self.identify(event.x, event.y)

    if name == "tab_btn_close":
        index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
        if index in self._non_closable_tabs:   # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            return None
        elif self._active == index:
            self.forget(index)
            self.event_generate("<<NotebookTabClosed>>")

    self.state(["!pressed"])
    self._active = None
```

Luego al agregar una pestaña, basta con usar el argumento `closable`:

```
self.nb.add(self.fm, text='INICIO', closable=False)
```

si se establece en `False`, el evento de cierre al hacer click en el botón se ignorará para esaa pestaña.

El código completo:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ButtonNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    _initialized = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._initialized:
            self._initialize()
            self._inititialized = True

        kwargs["style"] = "ButtonNotebook"
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._active = None
        self._non_closable_tabs = set()

        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_tab_close_press, True)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_tab_close_release)

    def on_tab_close_press(self, event):
        name = self.identify(event.x, event.y)
        if name == "tab_btn_close":
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            self.state(['pressed'])
            self._active = index

    def on_tab_close_release(self, event):
        if not self.instate(['pressed']):
            return None

        name =  self.identify(event.x, event.y)

        if name == "tab_btn_close":
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            if index in self._non_closable_tabs:
                return None
            elif self._active == index:
                self.forget(index)
                self.event_generate("<<NotebookTabClosed>>")

        self.state(["!pressed"])
        self._active = None

    def _initialize(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            style.theme_use('winnative')

        self.images = (
            tk.PhotoImage("img_close", data='''
                          R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2f///////////////yH5
                          BAEKAAIALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMUCCAsCmO5OBVl8OKhoV3e9jQOkAAAOw==
                           '''),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closeactive", data='''
                          R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2f///////////////yH5
                          BAEKAAMALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMPCDA8+gw+GGlVbWKqmwMJADs=
                          ''' ),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closepressed", data='''
                          R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2f///////////////yH5B
                          AEKAAMALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMPGDE8+gw+GGlVbWKqmwsJADs=
                          ''')
        )

        style.element_create("tab_btn_close", "image", "img_close",
                            ("active", "pressed", "!disabled", "img_closepressed"),
                            ("active", "!disabled", "img_closeactive"), border=8, sticky='')

        style.layout("ButtonNotebook", [("ButtonNotebook.client", {"sticky": "nswe"})])
        style.layout("ButtonNotebook.Tab", [
            ("ButtonNotebook.tab", {
                "sticky": "nswe", 
                "children": [
                    ("ButtonNotebook.padding", {
                        "side": "top", 
                        "sticky": "nswe",
                        "children": [
                            ("ButtonNotebook.focus", {
                                "side": "top", 
                                "sticky": "nswe",
                                "children": [
                                    ("ButtonNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                    ("ButtonNotebook.tab_btn_close", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                ]
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ])

        style.configure("ButtonNotebook.Tab", background="#fdd57e")         
        style.map('ButtonNotebook.Tab', background = [("selected", "Blue"),
                                                      ("active", "red")],
                                        foreground = [("selected", "#ffffff"),
                                                      ("active", "#000000")]
                 )

    def add(self, *args, closable=True, **kwargs):
        super().add(*args, **kwargs)
        if not closable:
            self._non_closable_tabs.add(self.index(self.tabs()[-1]))



class MiApp:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("650x250")                

        self.nb = ButtonNotebook(self.root, width=200, height=200)
        self.nb.pressed_index = None
        self.fm = tk.Frame(self.nb)

        self.nb.add(self.fm, text='INICIO', closable=False)
        self.nb.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        tk.Label(self.fm, text='Bienvenido a mi programa').grid()
        tk.Button(self.fm, text='SUMAR', command=self.sumar).grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
        tk.Button(self.fm, text='RESTAR', command=self.restar).grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

    def sumar(self):
        fm_sumar = tk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(fm_sumar, text='Pestaña de sumar')
        self.nb.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

    def restar(self):
        fm_restar = tk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(fm_restar, text='Pestaña de restar')
        self.nb.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = MiApp()
    master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo superponiendo un ttk.Button sobre la primera pestaña, el boton puede tener el mismo estilo y tamaño del tab principal. luego en el command del boton asignas el codigo para que se active esa pestaña.

```
class MiApp:
def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()        
    self.root.title("Mi Apliacion Python")
    self.root.state('zoomed') 
    self.nb = ButtonNotebook(self.root, width=200, height=200)
    self.nb.pressed_index = None
    self.fm = tk.Frame(self.nb)

    self.nb.add(self.fm, text="Mi Aplicación", closable=False)
    self.nb.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    
            
    #agregar un boton que se superponga a la pestaña
    def Home():
        self.nb.select(0)
    style = ttk.Style()
    #aplicamos al boton el mismo estilo de los tabs de notebook
    style.configure("ButtonTab.Tab", background="#FF5733", foreground= "white", padding=[13, 8])         
    style.map('ButtonTab.Tab', background = [("selected", "#FF5733"),
                                                  ("active", "#FF5732")],
                                    foreground = [("selected", "white"),
                                                  ("active", "white")]
             )
    MainTab = ttk.Button(self.root, text = "Mi Aplicación", style="ButtonTab.Tab", command=Home)
    MainTab.place(in_=self.nb, relx=0, rely=0)
```